# how to solve the linux timer signal handler

Tags: c++, c, linux, timer, handler

why is not possible to have a multiple timer with single handler. I used the program from the below link and it is not working. He has explained the reason about the problem but it is not very clear. Is someone help me why is it not working ??
http://www.graphics-muse.org/wp/?p=868

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason you can't have multiple timers created with `timer_create` using the same handler, provided your `sigval` structure contains enough information to distinguish between them as needed in  your handler.

Comment: did you check the above link in my question?? you can do in that!! but in some cases it is not possible

Comment: I think I'm making the same point as he is. Your handler needs to distinguish between which of the timers is going off.

Comment: @user3354789, abligh is correct.  You need to flip the switch from thinking you are right to understanding why you are wrong.  In fairness the code in that example is rather crappy and only goes  3/4ths of the way in illustrating how things work.

Comment: how to call the specific task for every 2ms, 10ms and 100ms ??

Answer (score 2):

The point of the article is that it *is* possible to have multiple timers trigger the same handler but you need to differentiate them based on some passed data.  Oddly the example the author used only went 3/4th of the distance of illustrating this in the code so maybe that is the source of your confusion.

Hopefully this reworking of the article's program is a bit clearer.  It uses the sival_ptr to point to a string but it can point to any type.  This is how the timers are differentiated.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define errExit(msg) do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

void timerHandler( int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc )
{
    // obligator caution not to use printf and other async-unsafe calls
    // in a handler in real programs

    printf("I am timer %s\n", (char *) si->si_value.sival_ptr);
}

void makeTimer(char *name, int intervalMS)
{
    struct sigevent         te;
    struct itimerspec       its;
    struct sigaction        sa;
    int                     sigNo = SIGRTMIN;

    // Set up signal handler.
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = timerHandler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);

    if (sigaction(sigNo, &sa, NULL) == -1)
        errExit("sigaction");

    // Set up timer
    te.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    te.sigev_signo = sigNo;
    te.sigev_value.sival_ptr = name;

    timer_t timerID;

    if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &te, &timerID) == -1)
        errExit("timer_create");

    its.it_value.tv_sec = intervalMS;
    its.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
    its.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    its.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

    if (timer_settime(timerID, 0, &its, NULL) == -1)
        errExit("timer_settime");

    return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *arr[3] = {"number one", "number two", "number three"};

    makeTimer(arr[0], 1);
    makeTimer(arr[1], 2);
    makeTimer(arr[2], 3);

    while (sleep(5));

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: but how to call the specific task for every 2ms, 10ms and 100ms ??

Comment: how different is your code from the link which I posted above ??

Comment: The changes I made were mostly taking out extraneous stuff and changing the ptr to point to strings instead of timer ids to ease the illustration of how this done.  As for the specific tasks in your earlier pgm you were doing this in a loop.  You only have to set the timers once and set the intervals so they are repeatedly fired.

Comment: thank you very much for the reply. Could you see my complete code in the below link and answer my problem in that case : http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=5125669#post5125669

Comment: what is the condition in your timer handler to check for calling the specific task. Example : if it is arr[0] - I have to call the specific function. arr[1] - then another task.